# Why am I getting different structures for LPUNKNOWN object in Windows 7 and Windows XP

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

Our application's code base is Visual C++ 98.  For Windows 7 users, the application throws an error from the OLE module that it doesn't throw from Windows XP.

I have two development systems that I'm using to trace the code.  One is Windows 7 Professional 64-bit and the other is Windows XP Professional 32-bit.  Each has its own install of VS 6 and separate (identical) copies of the full code base.  The problem area appears to be in the OLECLI1.CPP module (Microsoft MFC code) in

```
void COleClientItem::ReadItemCompound(CArchive& ar)
```

There are breakpoints at identical locations in the file:

```
else
{
    // get item name
    TCHAR szItemName[OLE_MAXITEMNAME];
    GetItemName(szItemName);

    // open storage for this item
    LPSTORAGE lpStorage;
    SCODE sc = pDoc->m_lpRootStg->OpenStorage(T2COLE(szItemName), NULL,
        STGM_READWRITE|STGM_TRANSACTED|STGM_SHARE_EXCLUSIVE,
        0, 0, &lpStorage);
    if (sc != S_OK)
    {
        TRACE1("Warning: unable to open child storage %s.\n", szItemName);
        // upon failure throw file exception (item will be cleaned up)
        AfxThrowOleException(sc);
    }
    ASSERT(lpStorage != NULL);

    // remember the storage
    m_lpStorage = lpStorage;
    ASSERT(m_lpStorage != NULL);
    // attempt to load the object from the storage
    LPUNKNOWN lpUnk = NULL;

>>>> BREAKPOINT <<<<

    sc = ::OleLoad(m_lpStorage, IID_IUnknown, GetClientSite(),
        (LPLP)&lpUnk);
    CheckGeneral(sc);
    // get IOleObject interface for the newly loaded object
    ASSERT(lpUnk != NULL);
    m_lpObject = QUERYINTERFACE(lpUnk, IOleObject);
    lpUnk->Release();
    if (m_lpObject == NULL)
        AfxThrowOleException(E_OUTOFMEMORY);
}
```

The problem appears to be in the way the two systems handle the definition of `lpUnk`.  `LPUNKNOWN` is defined in `AFXWIN.H` and is identical on the two systems, although on the Win7-64 system it's in "Program Files (x86)."

Windows XP watch box:

```
lpUnk   0x00000000
    lpVtbl  CXX0017: Error: symbol "" not found
```

Windows 7 watch box:

```
lpUnk   0x00000000
    __vfptr CXX0030: Error: expression cannot be evaluated
```

In the XP system, `sc` gets the value `0` after the call.  In the Win7 system, it gets set to `-2147418113`.  The `CheckGeneral(sc)` function compares `sc` and `S_OK` and throws an error if they're different.  Since the two values are different in Windows 7, it does.  Is there something different I have to do?  Am I missing a setting on the Windows 7 system?

---

UPDATE:  This morning, I looked more closely at what was returned from the `GetClientSite()` routine.  The code in MFC is fairly simple:

```
LPOLECLIENTSITE COleClientItem::GetClientSite()
{
    ASSERT_VALID(this);

    LPOLECLIENTSITE lpClientSite = 
        (LPOLECLIENTSITE)GetInterface(&IID_IOleClientSite);
    ASSERT(lpClientSite != NULL);
    return lpClientSite;
}
```

I also see that the definition of `LPOLECLIENTSITE` provides for two interfaces and the one I'm getting is the "C style interface."

```
typedef struct IOleClientSiteVtbl
{
    BEGIN_INTERFACE

    HRESULT ( STDMETHODCALLTYPE __RPC_FAR *QueryInterface )( 
        IOleClientSite __RPC_FAR * This,
        /* [in] */ REFIID riid,
        /* [iid_is][out] */ void __RPC_FAR *__RPC_FAR *ppvObject);

    ULONG ( STDMETHODCALLTYPE __RPC_FAR *AddRef )( 
        IOleClientSite __RPC_FAR * This);

    ULONG ( STDMETHODCALLTYPE __RPC_FAR *Release )( 
        IOleClientSite __RPC_FAR * This);

    HRESULT ( STDMETHODCALLTYPE __RPC_FAR *SaveObject )( 
        IOleClientSite __RPC_FAR * This);

    HRESULT ( STDMETHODCALLTYPE __RPC_FAR *GetMoniker )( 
        IOleClientSite __RPC_FAR * This,
        /* [in] */ DWORD dwAssign,
        /* [in] */ DWORD dwWhichMoniker,
        /* [out] */ IMoniker __RPC_FAR *__RPC_FAR *ppmk);

    HRESULT ( STDMETHODCALLTYPE __RPC_FAR *GetContainer )( 
        IOleClientSite __RPC_FAR * This,
        /* [out] */ IOleContainer __RPC_FAR *__RPC_FAR *ppContainer);

    HRESULT ( STDMETHODCALLTYPE __RPC_FAR *ShowObject )( 
        IOleClientSite __RPC_FAR * This);

    HRESULT ( STDMETHODCALLTYPE __RPC_FAR *OnShowWindow )( 
        IOleClientSite __RPC_FAR * This,
        /* [in] */ BOOL fShow);

    HRESULT ( STDMETHODCALLTYPE __RPC_FAR *RequestNewObjectLayout )( 
        IOleClientSite __RPC_FAR * This);

    END_INTERFACE
} IOleClientSiteVtbl;
```

I also note that on the Windows 7 system, `lpClientSite` doesn't seem to be fully defined.

[image: lpClientSite contents]

But the object on the XP system has everything:
[image]

Comment: -2147418113 is `E_UNEXPECTED` (0x8000FFFF).

Comment: What happens if you copy the binaries (EXEs, DLLs etc) from one machine to the other (instead of recompiling separately on each machine)? That would at least hint whether you have a runtime problem vs. a build problem.

Comment: Also, the return value of the GetClientSite() call is not checked.

Comment: The code in question appears to be from the MFC version that shipped with VC++6 (MFC 4.2, probably). Lots of bugfixes have been released in the meantime, and you should seriously consider updating to something more recent (preferably from this millennium).

Comment: Your assessment of the code is correct.  And I agree.  However, it's a commercial application with code that dates to 1987 and isn't easily ported up.  I will check to see if both versions are at the same service pack level.  It's possible that the Win7 system wasn't patched up.

Comment: Also, dxiv, I don't dare mess with this code, since it's the core MFC modules delivered by Microsoft.  If you think it'll help, I'll post the "watch" value of the object returned by the GetClientSite() part of the call.

Comment: The structures for `LPUNKNOWN` (`IUnknown*`) are identical across all Windows versions: A `struct` containing a pointer to an array with function pointers to `QueryInterface`, `AddRef`, and `Release`. When compiling as C++ this maps to a `class` with a v-table, that is implicitly assigned the symbol `__vfptr`. In C the pointer is explicitly named `lpVtbl`. The different display could be due to different debug engines, that use different symbol lookup, or different symbol server settings, or different debug visualizers in the *autoexp.dat* file. It's nothing to worry about, though.

Comment: Somehow your C++ code on Windows XP is using the C definition for `LPUNKNOWN` (which uses an explicit structure with function pointers) but you are getting the C++ definition on Windows 7 (which uses a class with virtual methods). The two are layout compatible, but you program to them differently. Its not clear whether you are running the same binary on both systems, or whether you are recompiling.

Comment: Note that on both systems, `lpUnk` is `NULL`, so there is no behavior change. It's just being reported differently by the debugger. You need to debug the actual behavior change

Comment: @RaymondChen, the code is identical.  I've done a complete rebuild on both code bases, my active configuration is "debug" and I'm running the source through the debugger.  The core application installed on both systems is the same.  I'm all for the idea of revamping my application's code to work appropriately, but at this point, am I too deep into MFC to impact how it behaves?

Comment: If you are running the same code on both systems, then I don't understand why the debugger is showing different structures. At any rate, the pointers are equivalent; the problem not there. The problem is that the `OleLoad` is failing. Maybe a CLSID is not registered on the Windows 7 system? Maybe the storages are not identical?